# How to pull event from function

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, js

Can u help me and tell how can I use `event.detail.row.ticker` in `@api tic = ;`

(I am realy bad in JS and =I don't know how can I pull it out.)

**JS**

```
companySymbol ='';
@api tic = ;

  @wire(getAndParseTickerDetails, { companySymbol: '$tic'}) sth;
  

handleClick(event) {
    
  if(event.detail.action.name==='first_button') {
    //let ticker = event.detail.row.ticker;
    objectApiName = event.detail.row.ticker;
            console.log('clicked FIRST button');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail.row));

            console.log(event.detail.row.ticker);

            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.sth));
            
            
           

    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Company Name',
        message: event.detail.row.name,
        variant: this.variant,
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    this.openModal();
    
  } 
  
    
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it's as simple as writing:

```
this.tic = event.detail.row.ticker
```

Where `this` means *access the current component instance* and `.tic` means *access the property `tic` from the instance*.

Since the wire method is reactive (`'$tic'`), this will cause the `sth` variable to be refreshed by the wire handler.